# Ошибка при использовании Qt Gui в DLL

Tags: qt, dll

Задача такая, написать на Qt DLL Что бы при загрузки DLL открывалось окно к примеру с QLabel.

Версия Qt: Qt 5.6.2 статическая сборка

```
#include <QtWidgets/QMessageBox>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QString>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static void startup() {
  int argc = 1;
  char *argv[] = {"D:\\Project\\build-injectDLLm-MinGw-Release\\release\\injectDLLm.dll"};

  QApplication app(argc,argv);
  QLabel l;
  l.setText("Example text label");
  l.show();
  app.exec();
}

extern "C" BOOL APIENTRY DllMain (HINSTANCE hInst, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    switch (reason)
    {
      case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            startup();
        break;

      case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;

      case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;

      case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

После загрузки DLL выходит вот такая ошибка:
[image: error]

файл **.pro**

```
QT += gui widgets

TARGET = injectDLLm
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += dll

DEFINES += INJECTDLLM_LIBRARY
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += injectdllm.cpp

HEADERS += injectdllm.h\
        injectdllm_global.h

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

Comment: При сборке "обычных" Qt приложений такая ошибка лечится добавлением файла qwindws.dll в папку platforms в папке с бинарником. Есть мнение, что и с библиотекой поможет.

Comment: Так у меня Qt 5.6.2 статическая сборка

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins